# Jquery animate from display none doesn't work first time

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a little block that I want to animate. But I want it to start from a hidden position, like this:

```
<span class="add_sit" style="height:18px; display:none"><input name="situacao"></span>
<img src="plus-circle-blue.png" class="picto" id="lnk_add_sit">


<script>
$(function(){
    $('#lnk_add_sit').css('cursor','pointer').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.add_sit').animate({width:'toggle'}, 'fast');
    });
});
</script>
```

This does not animate at first click, only shows the element. At second click, animates the element and changes to display:nome, at third click animates and changes to display:inline-block; and so on.

Only the first won't work. How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to run the toggle once on load instead of setting display to none:

```
<span class="add_sit" style="height:18px;"><input name="situacao"></span>
<img src="plus-circle-blue.png" class="picto" id="lnk_add_sit">


<script>
$(function(){
    var addSit = $('.add_sit');
    addSit.animate({width:'toggle'}, 0); // run it once to hide
    $('#lnk_add_sit').css('cursor','pointer').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        addSit.animate({width:'toggle'}, 'fast');
    });
});
</script>​
```

Here is a fiddle (just click the broken image icon):

http://jsfiddle.net/c5h4D/

Comment: Just so everyone knows, the image has no `alt` attribute so it will be completely blank in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

You can change...

```
<span class="add_sit" style="height:18px; display:none"><input name="situacao"></span>
```

...to...

```
<input name="situacao" class="add_sit" style="display: none">
```

...and run it that way.

**Check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matthewbj/FPn9T/)**

You can leave the parent span with the height, but remember that `<span>` is an inline element, the height property will not effect it unless you tell it to be `display:inline-block` or `display:block`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should give width to "add_sit", for example

```
<span class="add_sit" style="height:18px; display:none">
```

so jQuery knows the width of the element.

Answer (score 0):

You are animating the wrong element, you should animate the input not the parent that has no width set, and closing the elements is always a good idea:

```
<span class="add_sit" style="height:18px;">
    <input name="situacao" id="myInput" style="display: none;"/>
</span>
<img src="plus-circle-blue.png" class="picto" id="lnk_add_sit" />


<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#lnk_add_sit').css('cursor','pointer').click(function() {
        $('#myInput').animate({width: 'toggle'}, 'fast');
    });
});
</script>​​​​​​​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/svMpD/)